# Can we disable cron services in desktop?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, security, cron, malware

I was reading about [EvilGnome](https://thehackernews.com/2019/07/linux-gnome-spyware.html) and how it hijacks a system. One of the interesting thing I read was how it uses crontab

> The Linux implant also gains persistence on a targeted system using
>   crontab, similar to windows task scheduler, and sends stolen user data
>   to a remote attacker-controlled server.

In my ubuntu desktop I myself doesn't have any custom cron jobs but when I did `service cron status` it returned some results.

```
systemd[1]: Started Regular background program processing daemon. 
cron[916]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
cron[916]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
CRON[19931]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
CRON[19932]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
CRON[19931]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

My question is can I disable cron jobs something like `sudo systemctl disable cron.service`? Is cron a necessary service for a ubuntu desktop or can I completely remove this from my system?

Comment: "EvilGnome malware masquerades itself as a legit GNOME extension, a program that lets Linux users extend the functionality of their desktops." I would advice against using any extension to start with. It was a bad design decision to start forcing extensions by GNOME developers to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

*Note:* This is for companies with multi-million dollar yearly operating budgets. It would take a week to setup and requires an hour or two after upgrades to audit and even more to incorporate new scripts from an upgrade.

In comments it was mentioned `logrotate` gets called daily. This is an important part of Ubuntu for keeping log files down to size. If you are so concerned about `cron` you pull it fro mservice you would have to create your own script which mimicked `cron`. I'll call this script `crony`. You can keep it locked down in a place hackers wouldn't think to look for it.

Let's look at the files in `/etc/cron.daily`:

```bash
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   311 Feb 19  2014 0anacron*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   376 Apr  4  2014 apport*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1474 Oct 31  2016 apt-compat*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   314 Nov 26  2015 aptitude*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   355 Jun  4  2013 bsdmainutils*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   384 Mar 23  2014 cracklib-runtime*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1597 Nov 26  2015 dpkg*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    37 Jun  4 01:43 google-chrome -> /opt/google/chrome/cron/google-chrome*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  7613 Jan 17  2017 google-earth*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 13944 Mar  4 17:48 google-earth-pro*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   372 Jan 22  2014 logrotate*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1293 Nov  6  2015 man-db*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   435 Jun 20  2013 mlocate*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   249 Feb 16  2014 passwd*
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   102 Feb  9  2013 .placeholder
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  3449 Feb 26  2016 popularity-contest*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   383 Mar  7  2016 samba*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   214 Apr  9  2014 update-notifier-common*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1046 May 19  2016 upstart*
```

The script `mlocate` I don't even use daily. I have it run every 15 minutes because daily isn't enough for my liking. the script `popularity-contest` is [kind of like spyware](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57808/what-is-the-popularity-contest-package-for) so I wouldn't call it with `crony` if I were replacing `cron`.

I would call all my `crony` scrips from `/etc/rc.local` but there are other ways of doing it.

The format would be like this:

```bash
$ cat /etc/rc.local

#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Jan 05 2018 - Reload Logitech Unifying Receiver to get Mouse in Power Stats
modprobe -r hid_logitech_dj
modprobe    hid_logitech_dj

# Call crony to mimick cron's duties
# daemonize job   boot delay   sleep interval
crony /etc/cron.daily/mlocate 1m 15m &
crony /etc/cron.daily/logrotate 30m d &
crony /mnt/e/usr/local/bin/daily-backup 5m d &
corny /usr/local/bin/eyesome-sun.sh 1m d &

exit 0
```

This is what a typical installation has for entries that are already setup in `/etc/rc.local` along with new `crony` entries after them. The last two of my `crony` entries are custom scripts my machine has in `/etc/cron.daily`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: crony
# PATH: /usr/local/bin
# DATE: July 17, 2019
# NOTE: For Ask Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159014/can-we-disable-cron-services-in-desktop

logger "$0"

sleep "$2"

while true; do
    "$1"
    # If if parameter 2 is "d" for 1 day interval we can't sleep for a day
    # because laptop may have been suspended. Use 10 minutes to minimize resources
    sleep 10m
    # Check if time to process job again. If not continue
    continue

done
```

`crony` script needs more work but you get the general idea. This may or may not be a good project for WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) in which case I may finish it.

Comment: Good news: In 18.04 and newer, Unattended Upgrades shifted from a cron job to a systemd timer. The cron job `/etc/cron.daily/apt-compat` is for folks who don't use systemd.

Comment: logrotate could be a problem: log files not getting compressed. mlocate too. the command locate becomes useless.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. BUT there are a couple of tasks active on our systems and those will stop too.

> Is cron a necessary service for a ubuntu desktop or can I completely remove this from my system?

I would suggest it is necessary but as always with Linux ... your choice to decide :) Might I suggest another method: why not flag changes to /etc/cron*/, /etc/crontab and /var/spool/cron/crontabs/*/*? That might be a lot less trouble as you get to keep the normal cron jobs active. Just need to create a watchdog and set it loose on those directories.

A run down on cron from my system (yours might have more, the same or less actions) ...

```
$ ls /etc/cron.daily/
0anacron      cracklib-runtime  man-db              samba
apport        dpkg              mlocate             update-notifier-common
apt-compat    google-chrome     passwd
bsdmainutils  logrotate         popularity-contest


$ ls /etc/cron.weekly/
0anacron  man-db  update-notifier-common

$ ls /etc/cron.monthly/
0anacron
```

So generally I would investigate any of these (like popularity-contest is all fine and dandy but I could live without it). mlocate might be an issue: that one updates the locate command so could be useful.  And so on. EACH of these you could run manually.

Each of the files will have an explanation:

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ more /etc/cron.monthly/0anacron 
#!/bin/sh
#
# anacron's cron script
#
# This script updates anacron time stamps. It is called through run-parts
# either by anacron itself or by cron.
#
# The script is called "0anacron" to assure that it will be executed
# _before_ all other scripts.

test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || exit 0
anacron -u cron.monthly
```

anacron has its own service:

```
$ systemctl list-unit-files | grep cron
anacron.service                            enabled        
cron.service                               enabled        
anacron.timer                              enabled
```

Now for the command (stop and start):

```
sudo systemctl stop crond.service
sudo systemctl start crond.service
sudo systemctl stop anacron.service
sudo systemctl start anacron.service
sudo systemctl stop anacron.timer
sudo systemctl start anacron.timer
```

(I did not test each of them ;) )

Plus there is more than that: a user cron is also active; you can disable those with ...

```
sudo touch /var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER
sudo chmod 0 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER
```

for every user on your system (make copies of the files please so you can restore them if you want to restore them) (oddly I have not found a systemd service for user crons and I doubt it is dealt with from cron.service).